# how to use "Using System.Data;" on monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop, system.data

I'm trying to access some data on access database using Monodevelop on Ubuntu.

I've tried to add `using system.data;` but then i'll get an error that the using system.data doesn't exists.

where can i find system.data library for Monodevelop?

---

Found the solution :
there is a solution pane on left side of monodevelop,
there i found a references folder , right clicked on that , and easily included system.data to my project.

Comment: Please don't edit the question, add the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

there is a solution pane on left side of monodevelop, there i found a references folder , right clicked on that , and easily included system.data to my project.